# Populate objects from inside callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Quite simply, it is possible to populate the object symbols from inside the callbacks?

Cursed closures of javascript!

```
var symbols = {};
markets.find(function(err, markets) {
   for(var market in markets) {
     symbols[markets[market].symbol] = markets[market].label;
   }
});

console.log(symbols);
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Now, that `.find()` call may be asynchronous, so that `console.log()` may print nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[async/waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) is the right solution for this problem. And since .find() is asynchronous, you can do a forEach as well:

```
markets.forEach(function(m) {
  symbols[m.symbol] = m.label;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know ***async***!